# Sonarqube: Same name for all sub modules (of a multi module project) in Code section

Tags: sonarqube

In the "Code" section of the sonarqube web application all sub modules of a maven multi module project have the same name. Only when highlighted with the mouse a tooltip appears with the correct name of the module. Is there a way to show the correct sub module name? In every module pom.xml the correct `<artifactID>` and module `<name>`are set. We are using sonarqube 6.7

[image]

Comment: Do you manually set property `sonar.projectName`?

Comment: The definition of `sonar.projectName` = Name of the project that will be displayed on the web interface. Set through `<name>` when using Maven. And the name is set. Ok but just to try it out: Where should I put the property? In sonar-project.properties or in a pom.xml in its <properties> section?

Comment: My point was to ensure it is NOT set. By default the scanner for Maven will take the `<name>` of each module. But if you override property `sonar.projectName` on the command line, or in your root pom (in `<properties>` section), then due to Maven property inheritance, it will be applied to all modules. You can investigate the properties generated by the scanner using `-Dsonar.scanner.dumpToFile=out.properties`

Comment: Any other solution possible to maintain sub modules name and change only the name of the project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Julien H. indicated in his comment I found a parameter in the buildserver sonar start script which set the 'sonar.projectName' to a fixed value. After removing it, the correct names appeared within sonar.